# Reduction of order in case of general $n$-th order linear ODE

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Suppose that
$$
(H)\qquad y^{(n)}+a_{n-1}(x)y^{(n-1)}+\ldots+a_1(x)y'+a_0(x)y=0
$$
is an homogeneous $n$-th order linear ODE. In addition, suppose that $y_1(x),\ldots,y_{n-1}(x)$ are linearly independent solutions of $(H)$. Is it possible to find another solution $y_n(x)$ such that $\{y_1(x),\ldots,y_n(x)\}$ are linearly independent ?

I know that if $n=2$, then we can use the reduction of order technic. Do we have something similar in $n$-th order linear ODE? Does Abel formula can be useful for this purpose?

Thanks.

Comment: Same idea. Take the derivative of the Wronskian $w$ of $y_1,y_2,...,y_n$. You get that it satisfies $w'=a_{n-1}w$. So, you can find $w$. Once you have $w$, you write it in terms of $y_n$ and that is a linear ODE in $y_n$ of order $n-1$.

Comment: Thank @Boxwood!